# I am getting errors in class connecting to database

Tags: php, mysqli

I am getting syntax error on nos 14 and 15. I just cant figure it out. any help

```
<?php

class connect_dbase
{
    public function connection(
        $host="localhost", $user="root", $password="london", $db_name="users"
    ) {
        mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db_name)
        if(!$mysqli) {
            die( "connection failed :" .mysqli->connect_error());
        } else {
            echo " Database connection successful";
        }
    }
}

$connect_dbase=new connect_dbase();
$connect_dbase->connection();

?>
```

Comment: You're missing a dollar and a semicolon on line 8 and another dollar on line 10.  If I add those in it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

There were a few things wrong with your code.

A missing semi-colon at the end of this line:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db_name)
```

Also, the conditional statement to check if DB connection is successful or not, always echo'ed "`Database connection successful`" even if bad credentials were entered.

You may now use the following:

```
<?php

class connect_dbase
{
    public function connection(
        $host="localhost", $user="root", $password="london", $db_name="users"
    ) {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db_name);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}


else {
            echo " Database connection successful";
        }
    }
}

$connect_dbase=new connect_dbase();
$connect_dbase->connection();

?>
```